# How to replace a certain instance of a character

Tags: java, replace

I don't know how to replace a certain character when I want to replace it, it just replaces all the instances in the string. What I've tried

```
String s = "thaba" //I want to replace h with a and vice versa along with b and a
for (int i; i < s.length; i++)
if (s.substring(i, i+1).equalsIngoreCase("a")) {
s = s.replace(s.substring(i, i + 1), s.substring(i - 1, i));
s = s.replace(s.substring(i - 1, i), s.substring(i, i + 1));
}
```

The Problem with this is it comes out with

```
thhbb
```

Even though I want it to come out with this:

```
tahab
```

Or if I input

```
thaflar
```

I want it to output

```
tahfalr
```

I know why this is happening but I have no clue how to make it replace only those instances
Any help is appreciated.

**FIX**

I meant the question differently, which I fixed above, it was worded somewhat incorrectly

Comment: regex is the answer? what are your other inputs?

Comment: Use a temporary placeholder value.

Comment: If you want a general solution you need to provide some more example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a method and use [`String.indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and [`String.substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to replace the first occurrence of each character, something like

```
public static String replaceFirst(String in, char a, char b) {
    int pos1 = in.indexOf(a);
    int pos2 = in.indexOf(b);
    if (pos2 < pos1) {
        int temp = pos2;
        pos2 = pos1;
        pos1 = temp;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1 && pos1 != pos2) {
        sb.append(in.substring(0, pos1));
        sb.append(b);
        sb.append(in.substring(pos1 + 1, pos2));
        sb.append(a);
        sb.append(in.substring(pos2 + 1));
    } else {
        sb.append(in);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can call it with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "tha";
    System.out.println(replaceFirst(s, 'h', 'a'));
}
```

Output is the requested

```
tah
```

**Edit**

To support your additional requested functionality, you must also track a start position. First, we can delegate our previous method to the new method like so -

```
public static String replaceFirst(String in, char a, char b) {
    return replaceFirst(in, 0, a, b);
}
```

Then, we simply call `indexOf(char, int)` to specify the minimum index -

```
public static String replaceFirst(String in, int start, char a, char b) {
    int pos1 = in.indexOf(a, start);
    int pos2 = in.indexOf(b, start);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1 && pos1 != pos2) {
        if (pos2 < pos1) {
            int temp = pos2;
            pos2 = pos1;
            pos1 = temp;
        }
        sb.append(in.substring(0, pos1));
        sb.append(b);
        sb.append(in.substring(pos1 + 1, pos2));
        sb.append(a);
        sb.append(in.substring(pos2 + 1));
    } else {
        sb.append(in);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally, we can call it with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "afab";
    s = replaceFirst(s, 'a', 'f');
    s = replaceFirst(s, 2, 'a', 'b');
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Which outputs

```
faba
```

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to do it with certain instances and not others, such as poaytra becomes paoytar and faba becomes afab?

Comment: @PsyCode This does the first from the left. faba to afab is two different character swaps.

Comment: But how would you swap all the a's with the previous letters, as when I said faba to afab, all the a's are swapped with the previous letter. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

String s = "tha"

s.replace("ha", "ah"); Is one way to do it.

s = s.replace(h, a); will result in taa

so when  you try to replace all the a's with h's you will get thh.

You need to do both characters at once.

Comment: What about when the input changes to something more complex?

Comment: When the input changes to something more complex, I would suggest using a regular expression. They take advantage of the string.replace() method and let you add all sorts of paramters of when to and not to select items.

Comment: You should add that to your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a placeholder letter such as x to hold the "a" value while you set the "h" value. Then set the "a" value to where x is.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Consider editing your answer with some example code to more clearly demonstrate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can store all indices, then replace them one by one..

```
        ArrayList<Integer> aIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> hIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

        // find all h's and a's
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='a')
                aIndexes.add(i);
            if(s.charAt(i)=='h')
                hIndexes.add(i);
        }

        // replace all a's with h's and vice versa
        for(Integer i : aIndexes)
            s  = s.substring(0,i)+'h'+s.substring(i+1);
        for(Integer i : hIndexes)
            s  = s.substring(0,i)+'a'+s.substring(i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store all indices, then replace them one by one..

```
    ArrayList<Integer> aIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> hIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

    // find all h's and a's
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)=='a')
            aIndexes.add(i);
        if(s.charAt(i)=='h')
            hIndexes.add(i);
    }

    // replace all a's with h's and vice versa
    for(Integer i : aIndexes)
        s  = s.substring(0,i)+'h'+s.substring(i+1);
    for(Integer i : hIndexes)
        s  = s.substring(0,i)+'a'+s.substring(i+1);
```